# Embedding C and C++ into a microchip

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I'm sorry, I'm lost.

I program microchips, and I primarily work in assembly, but I have much more experience in C and C++. I know that there is a way to embed C++ into the microchip, I just need to know how. If I need to make a clone of C++, I am willing, if someone will tell me how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean Microchip, the company that makes PIC processors, or "microchip" as a general word?

Comment: You have experience with C++ and you _still_ are willing to make a clone?

Comment: Do you want a C/C++ compiler that would compile code for your chips or what?

Comment: Why would you need a clone of C++?  Is there not a C++ compiler/linker available that targets the microchip you're using?

Comment: or a compiler with a backend you can replace/modify to spit out whatever it is your chip uses (like llvm)?

Answer (score 3):

1) Write program in C or C++.

2) Compile program.

3) (Optional) Test program on an emulator.

4) Burn program into desired microchip.

If you give us specific chips, we can give you more details of how each of the steps works.

Comment: Step 0:  Find compiler for your target architecture.